# Letterhead creation query

Tags: koma-script, letterhead, scrlttr2

I am new to Latex but wish to learn more.  Does anyone here know how to create a letterhead using Latex?  It will consist of a small image on the top left-hand side of each page and some text to the right of that running all the way to the right-hand side.  Please note I only know the very basics so will need a step-by-step answer.  I have already looked on the net but didn't understand the solutions I saw as they seemed to be aimed at more advanced people than myself.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this question: [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)

Comment: I recommend [putting a PDF with the letterhead in the background](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43989/3083).

Comment: Another relevant question with some example code: [Business letter template with letterhead on the side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55928/2693).

Answer (score 3):

The KOMA-Script class `scrlttr2` is a very versatile class to produce letters according to certain standards (e.g. the german DIN) allowing, for example, for the correct positioning of the address to be visible through the window of the envelope.

The following MWE is a very basic example of howto use the `scrlttr2` class with adjustments for your specific letter head.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, backaddress=false, headlines=3, headinclude=true]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\setkomavar{fromname}{Your Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Your Street 23, 42567 Your Town}
% replace \rule by \includegraphics{yourlogo} to get your logo
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}} 
% here are the letter head definitions:
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\usekomavar{fromlogo} %
    \usekomavar{fromname}, \usekomavar{fromaddress}}
\setkomavar{nexthead}{\normalfont\usekomavar{fromlogo} %
    \usekomavar{fromname}, \usekomavar{fromaddress}\hfill}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{letter}{Celebrity Name \\ Where they live \\ 23456 That Town}
\opening{Dear Celebrity,}

\lipsum % just some filler text to show the final layout

\closing{Yours truly,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Note that the head has to be defined twice (`firsthead` and `nexthead`), because `scrlttr2` internally uses two different layouts for the first page  and all consecutive pages, respectively.

For further details and many examples explaining the various options and parameters please se the extensive [german](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguide.pdf) or [english manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) of KOMA-Script.

Answer (score 0):

The best and authentic place to get the right information is ctan.org (http://www.ctan.org/search/).

May be 'akletter' package can help you. Try googling "LaTeX letter head template" to get some help. Start here for latexing https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45579/15717

Best Solution to learn Latex is "more practice and more examples each day". Try using latex for every documentation work. Read questions in this site and try understanding. If possible try answering them. Thats the way i learnt.